# Como fazer uma select para encontrar um registro entre dois valores?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Tenho uma tabela com os seguintes valores

```
#   valor_min  vlr_max  juros
1    0         1999         0
2    2000      2999       1.2  
3    3000      3999       1.3
4    4000      999999     1.4
```

Necessito de consultar essa tabela com o valor ex.: 2500,00  achar os juros correspondente, nesse caso seria a linha 2.

> Como seria o select nesse caso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que a query abaixo atenda:

```
SELECT juros FROM sua_tabela WHERE 2500 BETWEEN valor_min AND valor_max;
```

Comment: O objetivo é percorrer a tabela para encontrar alinha que melhor satisfaz o valor.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu minha dúvida

Answer (score 1):

Boas, a tua query seria algo assim:

```
SELECT juros FROM [tabela] where valor_min BETWEEN valor_min AND 2500 AND valor_max BETWEEN 2500 AND valor_max
```

Entretanto, quando publiquei vi uma query apresentada, mais elegante, e mais simples.

```
SELECT juros FROM sua_tabela WHERE 2500 BETWEEN valor_min AND valor_max
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas como vc disse já tinham postado. Mesmo assim muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from sua_tabela where 2500 >= valor_min and 2500 <= valor_max
```